# After upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 my screen constantly fades to black. How to fix?

Tags: unity, 14.04, nouveau

I have an NVIDIA 8600GT graphics card and am currently running the X.Org nouveau display driver.

When I boot I get a normal 14.04 login screen with no issues.
Once I log in I see my desktop as expected. Then when I click on the Unity menu icon in the top left the menu flies out as expected but the screen darkens a little over and over until I have a blacked out desktop. Mouse cursor remains normal though.

If I right click about the screen sometimes the right click menu with jog the desktop into visibility again but then it quickly reverts to the blacked out state.

Does anyone know of a fix for this issue?

Comment: This issue is driving me crazy, I keep getting random black areas. I've never had an issue like this before. If anyone else is having it can you let me know, even if you don't have a resolution to the issue.

Comment: Have you tried the nvidia proprietary driver?

Comment: @errikos I have tried that but still had the same result.

Comment: It appears to be something to do with my user account. When I created a new user account and logged in the problem was gone.